# 2D Running Game (in first person view) in as3/flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to learn to make infinite running games like temple run.... but at a very basic level. I am good at as3 and flash... and i have created all the graphics.... the whole scenario of the game is in first person view. And the graphics is all created in Flash.

Can anyone please suggest some tutorials or any techniques that i should use to make the objects look like they are coming from a far point and how i can write the logic of hitting them or escaping them.

Thanks for ur help... :)

Comment: you can use scale properties on your MovieClips/Bitmaps, distance would scale lower, you can use hit test Object, using as3 just use the z property

Comment: You probably won't get much help here, SO is for simply questions and answers, as opposed to suggestions or discussions. Your question may be better suited for a forum or the like.